# Getting SQLiteException while calling getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Above code is the part of intent service where I am accessing GinisTable class which is actually a DBHelper class.

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            DeviceInfoTable deviceInfoTable = new DeviceInfoTable(UploadGiniData.this);
            DeviceInfo deviceInfo = deviceInfoTable.getDeviceInfo();

            String generatedDeviceInfo = deviceInfo.getGeneratedDeviceId();

            GinisTable ginisTable = new GinisTable(UploadGiniData.this);
            List<GiniInfo> giniInfoList = ginisTable.getGiniInfoList();
}
```

My GinisTable class is as below:

```
package com.mastishka.pocketgini.database.tables;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mastishka.pocketgini.Config;
import com.mastishka.pocketgini.database.beans.GiniInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GinisTable extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TABLE_GINI                 = "ginis";
    public static final String FIELD_GINI_ID              = "gini_id";
    public static final String FIELD_NAME                 = "name";
    public static final String FIELD_PROFESSION           = "profession";
    public static final String FIELD_GINI_PIC_PATH        = "gini_pic_path";
    public static final String FIELD_EXPERIENCE           = "experience";
    public static final String FIELD_PRIMARY_MOBILE       = "primary_mobile";
    public static final String FIELD_ISD_CODE             = "isd_code";
    public static final String FIELD_GENDER               = "gender";
    public static final String FIELD_DOB                  = "dob";
    public static final String FIELD_LATITUDE             = "latitude";
    public static final String FIELD_LONGITUDE            = "longitude";
    public static final String FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE1        = "address_line1";
    public static final String FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE2        = "address_line2";
    public static final String FIELD_CITY                 = "city";
    public static final String FIELD_STATE                = "state";
    public static final String FIELD_COUNTRY              = "country";
    public static final String FIELD_PHOTO_ID             = "photo_id";
    public static final String FIELD_PHOTO_ID_NUMBER      = "photo_id_number";
    public static final String FIELD_PHOTO_ID_PIC_PATH    = "photo_id_pic_path";

    public Context context;

    public GinisTable(Context context) {
        super(context, Config.DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            +GinisTable.TABLE_GINI+"("
            +GinisTable.FIELD_GINI_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_NAME+" VARCHAR(128), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_PROFESSION +" VARCHAR(128), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_GINI_PIC_PATH+" VARCHAR(128), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_EXPERIENCE+" INT, "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_PRIMARY_MOBILE+" VARCHAR(15), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_ISD_CODE+" VARCHAR(15),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_GENDER+" TINYINT,"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_DOB+" VARCHAR(15),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_LATITUDE+" DOUBLE,"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_LONGITUDE+" DOUBLE,"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE1+" VARCHAR(64),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE2+" VARCHAR(128),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_CITY+" VARCHAR(128),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_STATE+" VARCHAR(64),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_COUNTRY+" VARCHAR(64),"
            +GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID+" VARCHAR(64), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_NUMBER+" VARCHAR(128), "
            +GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_PIC_PATH+" VARCHAR(128));");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public int insertGini(GiniInfo giniInfo) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_NAME, giniInfo.getName());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_PROFESSION, giniInfo.getProfession());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_GINI_PIC_PATH, giniInfo.getPicPath());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_EXPERIENCE, giniInfo.getExperience());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_PRIMARY_MOBILE, giniInfo.getPrimaryMobile());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_ISD_CODE, giniInfo.getIsdCode());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_GENDER, giniInfo.getGender());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_DOB, giniInfo.getDob());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_LATITUDE, giniInfo.getLatitude());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_LONGITUDE, giniInfo.getLongitude());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE1, giniInfo.getAddressLine1());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE2, giniInfo.getAddressLine2());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_CITY, giniInfo.getCity());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_STATE, giniInfo.getState());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_COUNTRY, giniInfo.getCountry());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID, giniInfo.getPhotoID());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_NUMBER, giniInfo.getPhotoIDNum());
    contentValues.put(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_PIC_PATH, giniInfo.getPhotoIDPicPath());

    int giniID = (int) db.insert(GinisTable.TABLE_GINI, null, contentValues);
    return giniID;
}

public List<GiniInfo> getGiniInfoList() {

    List<GiniInfo> giniInfoList = new ArrayList<GiniInfo>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+GinisTable.TABLE_GINI, null);
    /*if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            GiniInfo giniInfo = new GiniInfo();
            giniInfo.setGiniID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_GINI_ID))));
            giniInfo.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_NAME)));
            giniInfo.setProfession(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_PROFESSION)));
            giniInfo.setPicPath(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_GINI_PIC_PATH)));
            giniInfo.setExperience(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_EXPERIENCE))));
            giniInfo.setPrimaryMobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_PRIMARY_MOBILE)));
            giniInfo.setIsdCode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_ISD_CODE)));
            giniInfo.setGender(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_GENDER))));
            giniInfo.setDob(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_DOB)));
            giniInfo.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_LATITUDE))));
            giniInfo.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_LONGITUDE))));
            giniInfo.setAddressLine1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE1)));
            giniInfo.setAddressLine2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_ADDRESS_LINE2)));
            giniInfo.setCity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_CITY)));
            giniInfo.setState(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_STATE)));
            giniInfo.setCountry(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_COUNTRY)));
            giniInfo.setPhotoID(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID)));
            giniInfo.setPhotoIDNum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_NUMBER)));
            giniInfo.setPhotoIDPicPath(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GinisTable.FIELD_PHOTO_ID_PIC_PATH)));

            giniInfoList.add(giniInfo);
        }
    }*/
    return giniInfoList;
}
}
```

My stack trace is as:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ginis (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ginis
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
at com.mastishka.pocketgini.database.tables.GinisTable.getGiniInfoList(GinisTable.java:122)
at com.mastishka.pocketgini.services.UploadGiniData.onHandleIntent(UploadGiniData.java:99)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The above is the exception stack trace.

Comment: `getReadableDatabase()` does not return nulls. On error an exception is thrown. Have you accidentally overridden the method yourself with a stub `return null` version?

Comment: No I did not override the method.

Comment: Post your stacktrace, too.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't have a NPE but `SQLiteException: no such table: ginis`. Uninstall and reinstall your app in case you have an old database file in your device.

Comment: Tried this but this is not working

Comment: Actually I caught the issue. If we call getReadableDatabase function second time in another table then it does not call oncreate method. is there any solution for that. You can see this thing in above function onHandleIntent.

Comment: Put all your tables within the same database file into the same sqlite helper. The helper is for versioning database files, not tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the tables within the same database file into the same sqlite helper. The helper is for versioning database files, not tables

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the question comments. Good that you got the problem resolved. However, the question itself doesn't actually contain the necessary information to tell what the problem was. Voted to close as solved-not-helpful-to-others.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

By this:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = GinisTable.this.getReadableDatabase();
```

If work please mark the right

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the existing the database connection before creating a new connection.

```
public int insertGini(GiniInfo giniInfo) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // ...............
    int giniID = (int) db.insert(GinisTable.TABLE_GINI, null, contentValues);
    db.close();   //Close the database connection.
    return giniID;
}
```

In some devices this connection prevents from creating the new connection.

Comment: getReadableDatabase() will never return null, Please post your logcat so that we can help you better.

Comment: NullPointerException is not because of getReadableDatabase(), it s because of table doesn't exist in the database. This error may occur when the table name is changed after creating the table,Once uninstall the application, then install again,

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem.

The constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper doesn't call OnCreate., After this line:

```
super(context, Config.DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

You have to add a line either getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() which will call onCreate if not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What is Config.DB_NAME? Is there another call somewhere else in the project?

```
super(context, Config.DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

If that's the case, the database was created so the onCreate in this class won't be called and hence the table doesn't exist.

Solution is to put all tables together in one derived class of SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Perhaps on a device the old database version. Completely remove the app from device and change the version number `super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);` Last digit

**2.** Check patch to file with SDK version compatible

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
} else {
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}
```

**3.** Before connecting to DataBase the was set wrong locale. Like  `Locale.setDefault(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);`

**4.** Perhaps the database file has been opened previously.